# I want to mention the channel instead of the name with my Discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

On running specific commands my bot is supposed to answer and mention the channel to use, but it just writing the names of the channel instead.

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content.startswith('!nxtz'):
        await message.channel.send('No comments yet'.format(message))

    if message.content.startswith('help') or message.content.startswith('Help'):
        await message.channel.send('** You can describe your issue in #need-support . Staff will assist you shortly **,{0.author.mention}'.format(message, txtc))
            
    if message.content.startswith('!nlrp') or message.content.startswith('!NLRP'):
        await message.channel.send('** Join the teamspeak server as mentioned in #teamspeak-ip and then connect to the server on the IP given in #server-ip **,{0.author.mention}'.format(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

To mention a channel you should use the following syntax `<#channelid>`. As internally this is the way Discord manages channel mentions.

To get the channel id: right click the name of the channel in your discord server and select `Copy ID`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You simply use `channel.mention`. Here's an example:

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name = "need-support")
await message.channel.send(f'**You can describe your issue in {channel.mention}. Staff will assist you shortly**, {message.author.mention}')
```